# what is the implementation of function findViewById in android

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I just start to learn Android.
I know Android is the open source OS.
I use android studio for develop the software.
I known the function findViewById.
I want to know the implementation of this function.
I just see below.
Could you please help to show where I can see the implementation of this function in android studio?
  @Nullable
    public abstract View findViewById(@IdRes int id);
Thank you very much.

Comment: [there you are](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.findViewById%28int%29)

Comment: @Blackbelt don't forget that ViewGroup overrides this implementation http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#1629

Comment: Hint for the future: Hold CTRL and click on the method you want to further investigate. Same goes for variables, classes etc.

Answer (score 4):

The `findViewById` from View.java calls the `findViewTraversal`, but if your view is a ViewGroup, the function is overridden in ViewGroup.java:

**View.java**

```java
    @Nullable
    public final <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
        if (id == NO_ID) {
            return null;
        }
        return findViewTraversal(id);
    }
```

**ViewGroup.java**

```java
    protected <T extends View> T findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) {
        if (id == mID) {
            return (T) this;
        }
        final View[] where = mChildren;
        final int len = mChildrenCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            View v = where[i];
            if ((v.mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_IS_ROOT_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
                v = v.findViewById(id);
                if (v != null) {
                    return (T) v;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So it is just a for-loop, searching by all children views, observe that the `View.findViewById` is called again, so depending on your viewtree this search may cost a lot.

References: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#4570

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#22767

*Those files are huge, so you have to wait some time for loading*

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that every View has an ID so you just go though all until it finds a match.

However, I  have only been able to track this:

[Activity.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.findViewById%28int%29)

```
2071 public View findViewById(int id) {
2072     return getWindow().findViewById(id);
2073 }
```

[Window.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/Window.java#Window.findViewById%28int%29)

```
989 public View findViewById(int id) {
990 return getDecorView().findViewById(id);
991 }
```

[View.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.findViewById%28int%29)

```
17067 public final View findViewById(int id) {
17068     if (id < 0) {
17069          return null;
17070     }
17071     return findViewTraversal(id);
17072 }
```

[View.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.findViewTraversal%28int%29)

```
17028 protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
17029     if (id == mID) {
17030          return this;
17031     }
17032     return null;
17033 }
```

Looks like each View does have an id (*mID*), but the tracking did not lead me to any looping. Maybe I missed something, this computer took me 10 minutes to go though the pages so I will check again when back at home. Maybe someone can clarify this for us.